# Powering multiple DC gadget(Routers, switches, RPis etc) using a single smps will be efficient than multiple power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, adapter, efficiency

I have multiple DC gadgets (Routers, switches, RPis etc) so obviously multiple DC adapters too. I have two spare ATX SMPS. So I was thinking to modify one SMPS so that I can replace all those adapters with the single SMPS to run all my gadgets.
So my question is will it be worthy? I'm considering worthiness corresponding to the power efficiency. Will the single SMPS be more power efficient than running multiple adapters?

Comment: You can do it but you need to be very sure that the internal commons are all directly connected to negative and that, for example, there are diodes in the negative path of one of the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not be worth it. All power supplies have a certain power at which they're most efficient. A good supply will have an efficiency of around 80 % at a certain load. Usually they will have their best efficiency when you load them at around 50% - 80% of their full load. The small DC adapters you have now will operate at this point.

Even the most effcient ATX power supply usually needs a load of at least 100 W or so to be as effiecient as those small adapters. ATX adapters need to be able to supply a lot of power up to 350 W for the smallest. This means compromises are made regarding the efficiency at 50 W for example. I bet that all your small adpters will not consume much more than that 50 W and that together thy are able to convert the mains power more efficiently than an ATX supply can.

So: not worth it, stick to what you have, it's better than you think it is.

Comment: +1, Suppose I have 5 adapters, all of them wastes some power for stepping down & rectifying. So total waste of power by those 5 adapters will be less than the power waste by the SMPS??

Comment: It is irrelevant what causes the power loss in the power supplies. Anyway, rectifying is not a large part of it. It is not the number of adapters that is the issue. It is that 5 small, low power adapters are more efficient than one large, **optimised for 200 W** supply is.